# Couting nodes with onyl one child in BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, nodes, children

I am wondering how to count nodes with only one child in BST.
I tried something like this:

```
    public int countOneChild(Node x)
   {
       if(x == null)
       {
           return 0;
       }
       /*if(x.right == null && x.left == null)
       {
           return 0;
       }*/
       if(x.left == null && x.right != null)
       {
           return 1 + countOneChild(x.right);
       }
       else if(x.left != null && x.right == null)
       {
           return 1 + countOneChild(x.left);
       }
       else 
       {
           return 0 + countOneChild(x.right) + countOneChild(x.right);
       }
   }
```

but this isn't working, it returns me the same result 0 every time.
How can I do that?

Comment: Put in some `System.out.print` to see: If `x` is actually created, to see the value of `x.left`, and the value of `x.right`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom else clause has a copy/paste error I believe. It should probably be:

```
   else 
   {
       return 0 + countOneChild(x.right) + countOneChild(x.left);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, I can't believe. This mistake has taken me 2 hours.